# probability put n balls into 3 boxes

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, binomial-distribution

$n$ balls are put into three boxes $A$, $B$ and $C$ independently from each other with probability $p$,$q$, $1-p-q$.

Here $n$ is a natural number,and $p,q$ are real numbers such that $p + q \le 1$, $p>0$, and $q> 0$. The number of balls entering the box $A$ is $X$, and the number of balls entering the box $B$ is $Y$.  The joint probability distribution of $(X, Y)$ is given as follows.

$$p(X=i,Y=j)= \frac{n!}{i!j!(n-i-j)!}{p^i}{q^j}(1-p-q)^{n-i-j}$$

where $i,j \ge 0, i+j<=n$

questions: find probability distribution of $X$, and show that  X ~ Bin (n,p), find $E [Y | X = i]$ and $E[Y]$.

I dont quite understand how can to get the $X$ and $Y$ distributons from joint distribution with multiple distribution, 
for $X$ is $P(X=i)= \binom{n}{i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i}?$
and why this should use binomial distribution?

$P(X=i)= \binom{n}{i}  p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$

$P(Y=j)= \binom{n-i}{j}q^j(1-p-q)^{n-i-ij}$

so the joint distributions $P(x=i,y=j)=\binom{n}{i}  p^i(1-p)^{n-i} * \binom{n-i}{j}q^j(1-p-q)^{n-i-ij}$ is enough to show that binomial?

Comment: I tried to fix some format and grammar, pls check. I also fixed the formula.
It's still unclear what's the question. First, it should be clear that the "given" joint distribution (a multinomial) is not part of the problem statement, it should instead be obtained as a deduction, trom the given model . If you understand that, it should be easier to obtain $P(X)$ (a binomial). To get $E[Y|X]$ you should first compute $P(Y|X)=P(X,Y)/P(X)$...

Comment: @leonbloy thankyou , i edit the questions, i need to show probability distribution of X is X ~ Bin (n,p) and find $E [Y | X = i]$ and $E[Y]$, the joint distributions is given in the problem, im not quite understand how can i get $P(X)$ from that joint distribution

Comment: First view each ball as a Bernoulli trial with success being "in A" and failure "not in A." The independence of the balls says that the number of successes (i.e. X) is distributed as Bin($n,p$). E[Y] should be $nq$ by the same reasoning. Given X=$i$, then ($n-i$) balls independently each have probability $q/(1-p)$ of landing in B....

Comment: @Ned thankyou but how to find X and Y distributions? $P(X=i)= \binom{n}{i}  p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$, $P(Y=j)= \binom{n-i}{j}q^j(1-p-q)^{n-i-ij}$ is this right?

Comment: @Ned why in B, has to be $q/(1-p)$? and not q?

Comment: In your first question, do you mean conditional (on X=$i$) or unconditional probability, that Y=$j$ ? Your left hand side is unconditional, right hand side is conditional.  For the second question, you know the ($n-i$)balls are not in A, so the conditional prob. that each one is in B is Pr(B and not A) / Pr(not A) = $ q / (1 - p) $.