# Joint Probability Distribution, Find $c$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am having a little bit of trouble with this practice question and I would like some insight of how to proceed.

> If $X$ and $Y$ are discrete random variables with joint probability:
> \begin{equation*}
> P(X = x, Y = y) = c\tau_x^x \tau_y^y(1 - \tau_x - \tau_y)^{n - x - y}
> \end{equation*}
> where $0 \leq \tau_x \leq 1$, $0 \leq \tau_y \leq 1$, $0 \leq \tau_x + \tau_y \leq 1$ and $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ with $0 \leq x + y \leq n$. Find $c$.

Below is my attempt to this problem:

We know that the sum of all joint probabilities has to be equal to 1. That is,
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{x \in X} \sum_{y \in Y} P(X = x, Y = y) = 1
\end{equation*}
Therefore, we want to determine a value $c$ such that the probability of the double summation will equal to 1.

Note that here, since $0 \leq x + y \leq n$, then $0 \leq x \leq n - y$ and $0 \leq y \leq n - x$. It can be shown that
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{x \in X} [P(X = x, Y = 0) + P(X = x, Y = 1) + \cdots + P(X = x, Y = n - x)] \\
&= \sum_{x \in X} P(X = x, Y = 0) + \sum_{x \in X} P(X = x, Y = 1) + \cdots + \sum_{x \in X} P(X = x, Y = n - x)
\end{align*}
Then let's have a look at one of the summations:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{x = 0}^{n - 0} P(X = x, Y = 0) &= \sum_{x = 0}^{n} c\tau_x^x \tau_0^0 (1 - \tau_x - \tau_0)^{n - x - 0} \\
\end{align*}
This looks like a sum of a finite geometric series, and recall that
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{x = 0}^{n} r^x = \dfrac{1 - r^{n + 1}}{1 - r}
\end{equation*}
Therefore,
\begin{equation*}
c\tau_0^0\sum_{x = 0}^n \tau_x^x (1 - \tau_x - \tau_0)^{n - x} = c\tau_0^0 \left(\dfrac{1 - \tau_{n + 1}^{n + 1}(1 - \tau_{n + 1} - \tau_0)^{-1}}{1 - \tau_1^1(1 - \tau_1 - \tau_0)^{n - 1}}\right)
\end{equation*}
This is the point where I got stuck and am not exactly sure how to proceed. Would appreciate the help.

Comment: I suspect, that you might have misread something in the practice question. I believe that the distribution should only have two parameters $\tau_X$ and $\tau_Y$. One for each random variable and not a $\tau$-value for each natural number from $0$ to $n$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3297172) the connection with binomial distributions.

Comment: Among all the apples in the world $(100\tau_x)$% are green, $(100\tau_y)$% are red, and the rest are yellow. You sample $n$ apples with replacement. Take $X,Y$ as the number of green and red apples, respectively. What is $\mathbb{P}(X=x,Y=y)$ equal to?

Comment: This is a [trinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution), so you can see what the answer should be.